# What tense should I use when referring to someone's children when some are alive and others dead?

Tags: grammar, tense, tense-agreement

This is the scenario: John had six children; two died, four are alive.

(Important Point: John is still alive)

Now someone wants to know about John's progeny, so he'd ask:

> "How many children does John have?"

What is the answer to this question? Four or Six, because present tense refers to someone who is alive.

This is a doubt: In the case wherein the asker intends to know the total number of children, will he use present or past tense. As in:

> "How many children did John have?"

or

> "How many children does John have?"

Comment: One way to answer this question would be: **He fathered six children (of whom four are alive)**

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question.

If someone asks

> How many children does John have

in the circumstances specified, the grammatically correct answer would be

> He has four children

because the question is framed in the present tense and so relates to the current situation.

In social practice, such a question would likely elicit a more nuanced response like

> He has four living children, but he had two others who died in a tragic car wreck five years ago.

You cannot use mere tense shifts to describe complex situations.